# Kivy widgets connected unexpectedly

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

A part of my application has a stacklayout holding some boxlayouts. I am trying to design a function that will enable dragging the boxlayouts to reorder them. I started by trying to see if by touching a button in the boxlayout I could get some of its unique data printed. This is when the boxlayout items started to "talk" with each other and pressing the button of any item prints info of the others too. I am not sure as to how this is happening and what I have to do to avoid it.
Code:

```html
class ExListItem(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, mytitle,myid,tag,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "horizontal"
        self.id = myid
        self.moveButton = Button(text="=", color=[0,0,0,1],size_hint_x=1, on_touch_move = self.emptify)
        self.titlelabel = Button(text=mytitle, color=[0,0,0,1], background_color=[1,1,1,1], size_hint_x=4)
        
        self.titlelabel.background_normal = 'rsrc/bbg.png'
        self.titlelabel.text = self.titlelabel.text
        self.FolderTag = Button(text = tag, color=[0,1,0,1], size_hint_x=2)
        
        self.remButton = Button(text = "x", size_hint_x=1)
        
        self.add_widget(self.moveButton)
        self.add_widget(self.titlelabel)
        self.add_widget(self.FolderTag)
        self.add_widget(self.remButton)
    def removeSelf(self):
        print(self.id)
        print(self.parent.items.__len__())
        self.parent.removeItem(self.id)
    def setParentList(self):
        self.parent:SingleStackList
        self.remButton.on_release = self.removeSelf
    def emptify(self, touch, move):
        print(self.id)
#the class for the stacklayout:
class SingleStackList(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.count = 0
        self.capacity = 2000000
        self.items = []
        self.refitems=maindata.I_images
        self.itemtype = "ImageFile"
        self.freeid = 0
        self.size_hint_x=1
        self.size_hint_y=None
    def clearStack(self):
        while(len(self.items)>0):
            self.removeItem(0)
    def setRefList(self, reflist):
        self.refitems = reflist
        templist = self.refitems[:]
        self.clearStack()
        for item in templist:
            self.addItem(item)
    def setItemType(self, typetext:str):
        self.itemtype = typetext
    def maxCapacity():
        print("Max Capacity of Stack Reached")
    def addGraphicalItem(self, itemdata):
        item = ListItem(mytitle = itemdata.name, myid=self.freeid,size_hint=(1, None), height=30)
        self.add_widget(item)
        item.setParentList()
        self.items.append(item)
        self.height = len(self.items)*self.items[0].height
    def addItem(self, itemdata):
        if(self.count>=self.capacity):
            self.maxCapacity()
            return
        self.refitems.append(itemdata)
        self.addGraphicalItem(itemdata)
        self.freeid+=1
        self.count+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do any collision checking or touch consuming in your touch handler, so it's called for every widget on every touch.

Add:

```
if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
    return
```

to your touch handler.

Comment: I added that line to emptify(self, touch, move) definition but there's no change. If it helps, I printed the touch coordinates and they all seem to be the bottom left corner of every ExlistItem's button

Comment: Update: Your solution is helpful. The problem was in the fact that my arguments for emptify are wrong. I should name them: self, button, touch.